# Merge two arrays with same length but different keys?

Tags: php

I have an array like:

```
[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["item_name_en"]=>
    string(7) "Salad 1"
    ["item_description"]=>
    string(3) "Yum"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["item_name"]=>
    string(7) "Salad 2"
    ["item_description"]=>
    string(0) "Yum"
  }
```

And another array like:

```
[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "25"
  }
```

How do I merge them both into 1 array where the result looks like:

```
  array(3) {
    ["item_name_en"]=>
    string(7) "Salad 1"
    ["item_description"]=>
    string(3) "Yum"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
```

They will always be the same length but never have the same keys. I already tried `array_merge` and also `$result = $array1 + $array2;` but that did not produce the desired result. There must be an easy way for this?

Comment: Use loop like `foreach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

**Initial data**

```
$a = [
    [
        "item_name_en"=> "Salad 1",
        "item_description"=> "Yum"
    ],
    [
        "item_name"=> "Salad 2",
        "item_description"=> "Yum"
    ]
];

$b = [
    [
        "price"=> "15"
    ],
    [
        "price"=> "25"
    ]
];
```

**Result**

```
$c = []; //New array

foreach($a as $k => $v){
    $c[$k] = array_merge($a[$k], $b[$k]);
}
```

**Output**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'item_name_en' => string 'Salad 1' (length=7)
      'item_description' => string 'Yum' (length=3)
      'price' => string '15' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'item_name' => string 'Salad 2' (length=7)
      'item_description' => string 'Yum' (length=3)
      'price' => string '25' (length=2)
```